# How do I wrap an unordered list around an image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In HTML, I'm trying to wrap a `ul` tag around an image. I need the right number of `li` tags to not overlap the image, no matter how tall or short they are. So far, I can get the content inside of the `li` tags to wrap around the image, but can't get the `li`s themselves to wrap around the image. Since each `li` tag has a bottom border, this isn't quite enough. You can see where I have it right now here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/

**How do I wrap an unordered list around an image so that even the li tags don't overlap the image?**

Comment: You're not wrapping anything around the image in your example. You just floated the image to the right. Does the opacity have to be .5?

Comment: Opacity should be 1, but I have it at .5 to show that the `li` tags are overlapping the image.

Comment: @j08691: The text is wrapping around the image.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - yes I realize the end effect of the float is the text wrapping around the image. I was referring to the code and that the img tag isn't wrapped by the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your new fiddle a bit, is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/21/

What I did was I

1. Removed the float from the description and instead just gave it a left margin (removed the right margin from the label at the same time since it's no longer needed)
2. Removed the clear trick from the `li`s because it was pushing the second `li` under the image and
3. Added `clear: left;` on the `li` element just in case you have a long label.

It doesn't change the fact that the `li` elements overlap the image, but at least the label and description elements are laid out properly.

Comment: That helped, thanks! I combined your method and j08691's method, and got it working in everything but IE7 (Where the floated text didn't quite line up). Because I actually needed the `div.label` element to be a fixed width, I switched to a different method of getting the text the way I wanted it to be. You can see the way I ended up doing it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/22/

Answer (score 2):

Give the **ul** element enough padding from left or right so that it wont overlap your image. For example, if your image is floated left and has 300px width, then your **ul** element should be:

```
<ul style="padding-left:300px">
```

or:

```
<ul style="padding-left:320px">
```

if you want some space between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it with some margin and an opaque image. See an updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/13/)**.

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

img {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 15px 15px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10;
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of expecting a "but my `<li>` elements have stuff on their right edge and I can't have the image hide them"

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen , it's something like that. In this case, it's that my  `<li>` tags each have two `float:left;` `<div>` tags inside of them. With the method my jsfiddle shows, inline content inside of the `display:block;` `<li>` tags wraps around the floated `<img>` tag correctly, but block level elements inside of the li tags don't work. I was looking for a solution where the `<li>` tags themselves wrap around the `<img>` tag correctly, so that the floated elements inside of each <li> tag just naturally behave themselves in relation to the <img> tag.

Comment: I just updated my jsfiddle to be more accurate to what I'm actually dealing with: http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/20/

Answer (score 0):

How about add `overflow:hidden;` to the LI tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/BBmER/153/

Comment: To the person that down voted, I'm interested to know why as I'm using this solution in production websites so if there's a situation where it doesn't work I'm keen to know about it.